# How to project 3D scatter points onto the xy-plane?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter-plot

this is the graph in question and the dots should appear *in the* bottom plane, not "above" the plane like i manged to.
[image]

```
bx.scatter(xs,ys,zs, zdir=zs,c=plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,N))) # scatter points
for i in range(N-1):
    bx.plot(xs[i:i+2], ys[i:i+2], zs[i:i+2], color=plt.cm.jet(i/N), alpha=0.5) 
   #plots the lines between points
bx.scatter(xs,ys,zs=732371.0,zdir="z",c=plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,N)),depthshade=True)   
 bx.set_zlim3d(732371.0,) #limit is there so that we can project the points onto the xy-plane
```

as youll notice the points are drawn above the xy-grid and I had to set a lower limit for the z-axis so that the first projected point will not interfere with the first scatter point

I would prefer the points be in 2d and less hacky since I got 50 other graphs to do like this and fine tune each one would be cumbersome.

Got some simpler method you want to share?

Comment: Why not just set the Z-coordinate to zero?

Comment: because the z axis is in datetime format, if i'd put 0 it would mean "start z axis in 1970" and the graph would be impossible to read. thats  why I used 732371.0 which is 2006-03-01, if I recall correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, and ultimately, it depends on the range of your data in the other plots.

1) Offset the projection point by a fixed amount
You could calculate the minimum Z value, and plot your projection a fixed offset from that minimum value.

```
zs=min(zs)-offset
```

2) offset the projection by a relative amount that depends on the range of your data.
You could take into account the range of your data (i.e. the distance from min to max Z) and calculate an offset proportional to that (e.g. 10-15%).

```
zs=min(zs)-0.15*(max(zs)-min(zs))
```

Comment: thanks. method 2 squashes all of the points on a plane but 1) works good